# Structure: Where put navigation bar component (Vue/ React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, frameworks

I have a quick question regarding components in frameworks like Vue or React (I'm using Vue):

I am building a relatively simple web app with a navigation bar which is **visible on all pages**.

Where would you put the navigation bar component? On **every single page**? Or only **once on the main parent** page where all the child components get loaded?

Comment: This is opinion-based. But I would suggest rendering it once and the sub-section below it. Use a router to determine which component to render in the section below the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes I know it is opinion based, but opinions are also worth it ;) Especially for beginners. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can call components from anywhere, you just need to create the component in a separate file in your components folder. **(mycomponent.vue)**

```
<template>
<h1>I am a component</h1>
</template>
```

and then in your view you need to import that component with:

```
import mycomponent from './mycomponent.vue'
```

and finally you just need to declare it inside your instance like this.

```
export default {
  components: {
    mycomponent
  },
  // ...
}
```

if you do this you are going to be able to print that h1 using in your view this tag.

```
<mycomponent></mycomponent>
```

it's like if you create your own html tag.

it's very simple, greetings, hope it helps just do it with your nav bar no with an h1.

Comment: there is another beautiful option if you want to use a fremework for vuejs, vuetify has some views by default with cool side navs that could help you to don't do that by hand and they are responsive.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined

Comment: Thank you, but this was not an answer to my question :) I know how to use Vue, it was just a question regarding the structure, or the Vue styling guideline. However, thank you for your effort :)